# In POSIX named semaphores, sem_unlink() removes the name of the semaphore

Tags: centos, posix, semaphore

The semaphore name is removed if 'there are no open references to the semaphore'(*)

- 1) What are these 'references'?
- 2) Can these references be queried to identify the involved processes?

The same paragraph continues to elaborate by 'if there are no open references to the semaphore, then it is destroyed. Otherwise, destruction is deferred until the last open reference is closed'.
This means to me that the OS will continue to query these references until it is able to destroy the semaphore.
Is there more to these 'references' than the value of the semaphore?

(*)W.R. Stevens, S.A. Rago 'Advanced Programming in the UNIX environment', 3rd Edition, pg. 581.

Answer (score 1):

## "What are these 'references'?"

> A named semaphore is identified by a name of the form `/somename`; that 
>   is,  a  null-terminated  string of up to **NAME_MAX**-4 (i.e.,  251)
>   characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by  one or  more 
>   characters,  none of which are slashes.  Two processes can operate on
>   the same named semaphore by passing the same name to `sem_open(3)`.

Thi basically means that a process that creates (**O_CREAT** flag passed to `sem_open(3)`) a named semaphore (in the form of `/somename`) will allow another process may operate on that named semaphore if has enough privileges (based on the process `uid` / `gid` that is creating that semaphore as well as the `mode` passed to `sem_open(3)`).

This is a simple way (analogous to two processes opening the same file) to **identify [and operate over] the same semaphore** on two or more different processes.

## "Can these references be queried to identify the involved processes?"

No (at least, in a POSIX way).

## "This means to me that the OS will continue to query these references until it is able to destroy the semaphore."

Although this is implementation specific, but there's no need to the OS keep querying the semaphore in order to determine if it can be unlinked. See that as a simple reference counter: If `sem_unlink()` is called by `Process#3`, but `Process#2` and `Process#1` are still using that semaphore, the reference counter to it will be 2 at this point. You just need to evaluate the reference counter value at every `sem_close()` or `sem_unlink()` call to determine when it reaches 0, then effectively unlinking the named semaphore.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
can a process execute an out-of-order sem_post() thereby causing a pending process to execute erroneously?

Comment: @ovi You don't need to worry about architecture level implementations. If you follow the POSIX [defined behaviour] specification, everything must work as expected.

Comment: my question is a result of an actual situation my application faces. User induced, asynchronous events can trigger a broken pair of wait-post. In trying to clean this up, an external process needs a way to unconditionally unlink and remove a semaphore. I have attempted to implement a clean-up process that puts in (arbitrary) 10 calls to 'post' and then unlink - and it seems to be working. I just want to make sure my solution, while brute force, is valid/legal.

Comment: @ovi I can't consider it a valid solution. Yes it may work in your case, but that does not solve the problem, only shadows it. The reason for that to work makes sense because if you increment the semaphore [with sem_post()] as many times as many sem_wait() are waiting for that semaphore to be greater than 0 to proceed, will cause all sem_wait()s to return, then unblocking all the processes [previously locked on sem_wait()].

Comment: There are only 4 possible participant processes to this semaphore. The count can't be greater than 4. I did not mean for this solution to be a full general purpose solution.

Comment: The 4 participant processes actually get killed by another process which is then tasked with clean up. The count can't be greater than 4 and I agree that my solution is not capable of handling an arbitrary number of 'waits'.

Comment: @ovi I didn't meant to say that your solution doesn't fit your current needs. Just wanted to say that, if possible, you may want to consider the re-design the application in order to avoid having a semaphore cleanup process. Although it works, it isn't the best way to do it.